# Пропадает отображения контента div блока, после переключения на другую картинку

Tags: javascript, css

При клике на картинки пропадает текст вовсе и не появляется как это исправить?

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.tab-content:first').show(0);
        $('.tab:first').addClass('selected');
        $('.tab').click(function(){
           $('.tab').removeClass('selected');
           $(this).addClass('selected'); 
           $('.tab-content').hide(0);   
           $(this).next('.tab-content').show(0);     
        });
    });
```

```css
    .tab{
    display:inline-block;        
    }

    .tab-content{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:55px;
    font-size: 40px;
    color:black;
    width:100%
    }

    .list_class{
      position: absolute;
        left: 28px;
        bottom: 193px;
        z-index: 20;
        width: 544px;
    }
    ul{
    list-style: none;
    }
    .list_class .link_darkknight:hover, .list_class .selected .link_darkknight 
    {
        background-position: -500px 0;
    }
    .list_class .link_class{
    display: block;
        width: 96px;
        height: 96px;
        background: url(https://akamai-webcdn.kgstatic.net/renewal/static/images/class/img_class_181211.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
        text-indent: -9999px;
    }
    .list_class .link_sim {
        background-position: -100px 0;
    }
    .list_class .link_sim:hover, .list_class .selected .link_sim{
      background-position: -600px 0;
    }
    a{
        color: #000;
        text-decoration: none;
        outline: none;
    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <ul class="list_class">
      <li class="tab">
       <a href="#" class="link_class link_darkknight">Dark knight</a>
       <div class="tab-content"><p>Text</p></div>
      </li>
      <li class="tab">
       <a href="#" class="link_class link_sim">hi</a>
       <div class="tab-content">Text2</div>
      </li>
     </ul>
```

Comment: Чтобы текст был на одном уровне убери <p>...</p> из первого. А в css для .tab-content поставь top:100px;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tab:first').addClass('selected');
    $('.link_class').click(function(){
       $('.tab').removeClass('selected');
       $(this).parent().addClass('selected');   
    });
});
```

```css
.tab{
display:inline-block;        
}

.tab>span.selected{
background:url(https://akamai-webcdn.kgstatic.net/renewal/static/images/class/img_class_181211.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
color:white;
}

.tab.selected > .tab-content {
display:block;
}

.tab-content{
display:none;
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:55px;
font-size: 40px;
color:black;
width:100%
}

.list_class{
  position: absolute;
    left: 28px;
    bottom: 193px;
    z-index: 20;
    width: 544px;
}
ul{
list-style: none;
}
.list_class .link_sim:hover, .list_class  .selected .link_sim {
    background-position: -500px 0;
}
.list_class .link_darkknight:hover, .list_class .selected .link_darkknight {
    background-position: -500px 0;
}
.list_class .link_class{
display: block;
    width: 96px;
    height: 96px;
    background: url(https://akamai-webcdn.kgstatic.net/renewal/static/images/class/img_class_181211.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}

.link_darkknight{
width:300px; height:200px; background:#ccc;
}
.link_sim{
width:300px; height:200px; background:#ccc;
}
a{
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list_class">
  <li class="tab">
   <a href="#" class="link_class link_darkknight">Dark knight</a>
   <div class="tab-content"><p>Text</p></div>
  </li>
  <li class="tab">
   <a href="#" class="link_class link_darkknight">Dark knight</a>
   <div class="tab-content">Text2</div>
  </li>
 </ul>
```